# Datable: sorting-arrows not responsive, how to get them to actually sort the table?

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

I have set up a table with very basic settings (oLanguage, bFilter: false, bSort: true) and it does show the sorting-arrows in the columnd headers (first col only shows up-arrow). However, clicking on any of the other arrows does not do anything...
How can I make them responsive?

(Error-Console does not show any problems)

Here's a slimmed down example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.01 Strict//EN">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>data</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="inc/jquery.dataTables.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="inc/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" />
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="inc/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="inc/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>      
    <script type="text/javascript" src="inc/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="inc/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>      

    <script type="text/javascript" src="inc/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>    
    <body>

        <table width="100%" id="vorgangsliste">
            <thead>

                <tr>
                    <th class="left" width="50px" align="center"> <b>ID</b> </th>
                    <th class="left" width="50" align="left"> <b>Termin</b> </th>
                    <th class="middle" width="100px" align="left"> <b>Author</b> </th>
                    <th class="left" width="*" align="left"> <b>Titel</b> </th>
                    <th class="FlowLine" width="50px" align="right"> &nbsp; </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class='oddRow'>
                    <td class="left" width="200px" align="center">BaasTest-20131114-0720</td>
                    <td width="100px" >
                    28.12.2012        </td>
                    <td class="middle" width="100px" align="left">Michael Baas</td>
                    <td class="right" width="*" align="left">
                        <a href="#">Manuell angelegt</a>
                    </td>
                    <td width="50px" align="right">
                        <a href="#">L</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class='evenRow'>
                    <td class="left" width="200px" align="center">BaasTest-20131114-0902</td>
                    <td width="100px" >
                    24.12.2012        </td>
                    <td class="middle" width="100px" align="left">Michael Baas</td>
                    <td class="right" width="*" align="left">
                        <a href="#">Nochmals manu</a>
                    </td>
                    <td width="50px" align="right">
                        <a href="#">L</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#vorgangsliste').dataTable({
                    "oLanguage": { "sUrl": "inc/language/de_DE.txt" }  ,
                    "bFilter": false,
                    "bSort":true
                }
                );
            } );
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**edit Nov 15th:** this is getting stranger and stranger: I managed to get my example to work by setting changing `"bfilter":true`. However, when I did that in my productive code, it did not have that effect. And surprisingly, when I then changed back `"bfilter":false`

Comment: Can you paste your code/html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my, that was a long and tough excercise - but finally I found the reason: in the statement `"oLanguage": { "sUrl": "inc/language/de_DE.txt" }`I was referring to a non-existent file. After finally providing that file at the correct location, it all works fine! :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a header for all the columns. If any of your table columns do not have a corresponding header then the arrows will be unresponsive.

Comment: As shown in my code above, all columns have a header. The last col's header is a space, but even when I enter "real text", it doesn't change.